# Software for capturing of selected text from any place (browser, text editor, etc)

Tags: software-recommendation, shortcuts, clipboard, notes

Please, give me advice about software which can capture selected text due to some shortcut in notes list.
Ideally, this should be something like CintraNotes on Windows.

---

This is solution which I like.
Autokey (install with next command)
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
Example of using 
http://chaalpritam.blogspot.com/2015/04/how-to-take-notes-from-pdf-and-webpage.html

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight text and then press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>C</kbd>  It will copy all selected text. Then you can paste it again with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>V</kbd>  You can also cut text which is copying and removing with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>X</kbd>  And then paste it with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon) can watch your selection and you can paste it with ctrl+v or the middle mousebutton.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. Unfortunately, I  was not looking for clipboard manager. I wanted application for grabbing of valuable content with using some hotkeys.  Clipboard manager grabs a lot of trash.